# Speed up Computation on Mac Pro

Tags: performance-tuning

I recently got the opportunity to switch my licence from a macbook laptop to a Mac Pro. Although being very ignorant on the topic, I know that the Mac Pro should perform computations much faster than my laptop.

My issue is that using the same notebook, it turns out that the running time is even slower on the Mac Pro! It is very frustrating. I am using this forum hoping somebody will shed some light on the topic and finally getting me out of this ignorance...

Here are the characteristics of my Macbook:
[image]

And here are the characteristics of the Mac Pro:
[image]

I am unfamiliar with the terms of Parallel computing. I am guessing that parallel computation only helps in specific cases and not per se for solving Matrix equations or simplifying long expressions. However I see that the speed of my processor is faster (3 Ghz) so it feels fair to think that running the same notebook on the Mac Pro should be faster.

Here is a screenshot of my preferences:
[image]
And here a screenshot describing the percentage of CPU used:
[image]

I have not found a similar question on the forum, however if someone shows me it is the case I can delete it as a duplicate, my apologies if it is the case. Of course any remark or explanation is always appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I remember the shock when I found that my then new 2011 MacBook Air was much faster than my MacPro for my Mathematica calculations. I was because the SSD drive. Are both of your computers using SSD drives?

Comment: I recently bought a shiny new 13" MacBook Pro, fastest processor available, 16GB RAM.  According to the Mathematica benchmark it is about 4 times as fast as my Mac Pro 3.1. OP writes *Although being very ignorant on the topic, I know that the Mac Pro should perform computations much faster than my laptop.*  Actually, no, not really.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Indeed, I only have a SSD drive on my MacBook. Did you notice a drastic change of performance after installing a SSD drive on your MacPro?

Comment: Thank you Mark. If I understand correctly, you are suggesting that the RAM has a bigger impact on Mathematica performance than CPU or number of cores?

Comment: No.  I also have 16GB RAM on my MacPro, and an SSD for that matter.  I'm suggesting that comparing the performance of two computer systems built 10 years apart is not a simple matter and that your expectations that the Mac Pro should outperform the MacBook Pro are naive. It's certainly not a simple matter of comparing raw CPU clock rates.

Comment: I start to understand it is not as simple as comparing numbers to evaluate performance. Nevertheless if I have a better processor, better ram, an SSD on the 10 year old mac pro, it should still outperform my macbook, shouldn't it?

Comment: Maybe "it should still outperform my macbook" in theory, but apparently you experience proves otherwise. Perhaps it is true for some software programs **other** than Mathematica. I am sorry that the actual performace disappoints you.

Comment: My final contribution: but the Intel Xeon on a 10 (?) yr old Mac Pro is not obviously a better processor than the i5 on a reasonably up to date MacBook Pro.  Intel haven't been sitting on their hands for the last decade !

Comment: Fair enough! thank you for your contributions, I understand better now.